# Função para descompactar xml não funciona no Linux

Tags: jsf, linux, glassfish, download, arquivo-zip

Na minha aplicação utilizo uma função para zipar os arquivos xml para salvá-los na base de dados. Quando eu o descompacto para disponibilizar o arquivo para download o xml não vem completo, no fim do arquivo vem sem um caractere e sem o fechamento da tag, por exemplo:

Ao invés de vim assim:

```
<NFse>
   Conteúdo...
</NFse>
```

Está vindo assim:

```
<NFse>
   Conteúdo...
</NFs
```

Detalhe que isto acontece apenas quando a aplicação esta implantada no servidor linux, na minha máquina (windows) o download ocorre perfeitamente.

Função para zipar:

```
public static byte[] compressBytes(String data) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    if (data == null) {
        return null;
    }
    byte[] input = data.getBytes("UTF-8");  //the format... data is the total string
    Deflater df = new Deflater();       

    df.setInput(input);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(input.length);   
    df.finish();
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];   //segment segment pop....segment set 1024
    while (!df.finished()) {
        int count = df.deflate(buff);       //returns the generated code... index
        baos.write(buff, 0, count);     //write 4m 0 to count
    }
    baos.close();
    byte[] output = baos.toByteArray();

    return output;
}
```

Função para descompactar:

```
public static String extractBytes(byte[] input) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException, DataFormatException {
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Inflater ifl = new Inflater();   //mainly generate the extraction
    ifl.setInput(input);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(input.length);
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    while (!ifl.finished()) {
        int count = ifl.inflate(buff);
        baos.write(buff, 0, count);
    }
    baos.close();
    byte[] output = baos.toByteArray();

    return new String(output);
}
```

Qual deve ser o problema, meu servidor linux ou algum código que está faltando?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Pior que ainda não rapaz! O erro continua acontecendo.